# Linq - Remove object in nested collections

Tags: c#, linq

```
Parent
    -Child1
        -GrandChild1
            -GreatGrandChild1
                -Name="Name One"
            -GreatGrandChild2
                -Name="Name Two"
            -GreatGrandChild3
                -Name="Name One"
        -GrandChild2
            -GreatGrandChild4
                -Name="Name One"
            -GreatGrandChild5
                -Name="Name Three"
            -GreatGrandChild6
                -Name="Name One"
        -GrandChild3
            -GreatGrandChild7
                -Name="Name One"
            -GreatGrandChild8
                -Name="Name Five"
            -GreatGrandChild9
                -Name="Name One"
    -Child1
        -GrandChild4
            -GreatGrandChild10
                -Name="Name One"
            -GreatGrandChild11
                -Name="Name Six"
            -GreatGrandChild12
                -Name="Name One"
        -GrandChild5
            -GreatGrandChild13
                -Name="Name One"
            -GreatGrandChild14
                -Name="Name One"
            -GreatGrandChild15
                -Name="Name One"
        -GrandChild6
            -GreatGrandChild16
                -Name="Name One"
            -GreatGrandChild17
                -Name="Name Seven"
            -GreatGrandChild18
                -Name="Name One"
```

I would like to select the Parent, Child, GrandChild and GreatGrandChild where GreatGrandChild's name is not `Name One`.

How do I do that in Linq.

I tried with `Select` , `selectMany` along with `Any` but it wasn't giving the desired result

**Note:** The collection is list of objects.

Comment: Linq is for querying data, not for removing or manipulating it. What is the actual type of the collection? Is this Linq-to-Entities or Linq-to-Objects or another Linq backend?

Comment: @Dai It is just List of nested objects.

Comment: Please post the definition of the objects - it's unclear if this a generic tree of identical object classes or if `Parent`, `Child`, and `GrandChild` are separate types.

Comment: could you edit the post and add the expected output data for the example data given?

Comment: Agreed with @Dai, without knowing the structure of the objects there's no way to show you a correct projection.

Comment: can you pst the actual json

Comment: _I would like to select the Parent, Child, GrandChild and GreatGrandChild_ Please clarify what kind of enumerable you expect to end up with: is each element going to be a Parent? Or are the elements going to be (successively) Parent, Child, GrandChaild, GreatGrandChild.

Comment: @Dai All Parent, Child, GrandChild and GreatGrandChild are of different types.

Answer (score 1):

Since we need to manipulate the collection (to remove great grand children with "Name One"), LINQ alone won't be sufficient.

```
//assuming it is ok to mutate the existing list of Objects (parents)

var grandChildren = parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children).SelectMany(c => c.GrandChildren);
foreach (var grandChild in grandChildren)
{
    grandChild.GreatGrandChildren.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == "Name One");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
parent.ChildList = parent.ChildList.Where(x => x.GrandChildList.Any(y => y.Name == "Name One") == false).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this doesnt work:

```
var hasAnyGreatGrandChildren = parent.Child.GrandChild
                                     .SelectMany(x => x.GreatGrandChild)
                                     .Any(x ==> x.Name != "Name One");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is a deep copy with condition of the first list.

here is a little exemple:

```
var parentWithoutNameOne = new Parent
{
    Childs = parent.Childs
                    .Select(o => new Child()
                    {
                        GrandChilds = o.GrandChilds.Select(p => new GrandChild
                        {
                            GreatGrandChilds = p.GreatGrandChilds
                                                .Where(l => l.Name != "Name One")
                                                .ToList()
                        }).ToList()
                    }).ToList()
};
```

And here are the definitions of the class i'm using:

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    public List<GrandChild> GrandChilds { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChild
{
    public List<GreatGrandChild> GreatGrandChilds { get; set; }
}

public class GreatGrandChild
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```